# Repeated pattern. Need help understanding a submitted solution

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, contains

Looking for some help to understand a solution someone else submitted. After I submitted mine, I looked at the others on leetcode to see the kind of solutions others came up with.

I came across one that was efficient and simple but I have a hard time understanding it.

```
string checker = (s + s).Substring(1, 2 * s.Length - 2);
return checker.Contains(s);
```

What I do understand : checker builds a substring between s+s starting at index 1;

String method `Contain()` checks for said string inside checker;
However, I may be confused about the fundamental nature of `Contain()`;

Example cases:

**1.abcabcabc**

ex 1. checker = "bcabcabcabcabcabc"; s checks for abcabcabc; The second should contains this since (s+s); this returns true;

**2.abababc**

ex 2. checker = "bababcabababc"; wouldn't it contain "abababc" bababc/abababc?; returns false;

How does `Contain()` actually work in C#? Preferably ELI5; please and thanks!

Comment: Would be nice if you included the question, I assume it's a Palindrome check? As for `Contains` method, see the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @LukeVo "Given a string s, check if it can be constructed by taking a substring of it and appending multiple copies of the substring together." The problem is the official doc, can't save me in this case. I am utterly braindead here. I thought I understood what Contain meant, but after this solution, I clearly don't

Comment: At a quick glance you have one too many characters in your concatenated string. The referenced code should remove first AND last character of the concatenation. Otherwise Contains would make no sense.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff and yet, this solution was passed as success. I doubled checked to make sure nothing was truncated and it does go all the way to the end of the string. nothing was cutoff

Comment: I don't think you followed me. On example #2, you evaluated `checker1` to `bababcabababc` but it actually evaluates to `bababcababab` which is one character shorter and does NOT contain the initial string.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff are you sure? I'm double checking, but I'm getting the same result. Am I missing something? Length of second problem is 7, 7 + 7 = 14 - 2 = 12; So checker goes 12 characters length which is the full length of the string 2 * s from index 1

Comment: Positive. Concatenated string is 14 characters (indexes 0 to 13). We take a substring of 12 characters starting at index 1 (indexes 1 to 12). We have lost index 0 AND index 13.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Oh! Thank you! I had a bit of a misunderstanding of how that second parameter worked. I looked it up again on C# docs to make sure. My misunderstanding came from Substring() rather than Contain() then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring length is twice input length minus 2, so the last character will also be truncated.  If the input is entirely composed of a repeating "phrase", then appending itself will manifest the input value in the middle of the concatenation result.  The first and last chars are truncated to avoid a match on the original input values in the concatenation

```
input => append input to input => truncate first and last char => result

ab => abab => ba => !contains(ab)
abc => abcabc => bcab => !contains(abc)
abab => abababab => bababa => contains(abab)
                     ^--^
abcabc => abcabcabcabc => bcabcabcab => contains(abcabc)
                            ^----^
```